# How to delete part of text in array?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python

I have this txt:

```
======== Data: 00:05:08.627012 =========            

1900-01-01 00:05:08.627012 ; 0 ; 1.16198 ; 10000000.0
1900-01-01 00:05:08.627012 ; 1 ; 1.16232 ; 10000000.0

========= Data: 00:05:12.721536 =========           

1900-01-01 00:05:08.627012 ; 0 ; 1.16198 ; 10000000.0
1900-01-01 00:05:12.721536 ; 0 ; 1.16209 ; 1000000.0
1900-01-01 00:05:08.627012 ; 1 ; 1.16232 ; 10000000.0
```

I need to remove '1900-01-01' but save time and change 0 to Bid and 1 to Ask

I stacked with this peace and cant figure out what to do next

```
readyColumns = []

for row in lines:
    row = row.strip()
    rowsAsArray = row.split(';')
    for element in rowsAsArray:
        element = element.split(';')
        print(element)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lines_block = '''======== Data: 00:05:08.627012 =========            

1900-01-01 00:05:08.627012 ; 0 ; 1.16198 ; 10000000.0
1900-01-01 00:05:08.627012 ; 1 ; 1.16232 ; 10000000.0

========= Data: 00:05:12.721536 =========           

1900-01-01 00:05:08.627012 ; 0 ; 1.16198 ; 10000000.0
1900-01-01 00:05:12.721536 ; 0 ; 1.16209 ; 1000000.0
1900-01-01 00:05:08.627012 ; 1 ; 1.16232 ; 10000000.0'''

lines = lines_block.split('\n')
new_lines = []
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('1900-01-01'):
        fields = line.split(' ; ')
        fields[0] = fields[0][10:]
        fields[1] = 'Bid' if fields[1] == '0' else 'Ask'
        new_line = ' ; '.join(fields)
        new_lines.append(new_line)
    else:
        new_lines.append(line)

for line in new_lines:
    print(line)
```

output

```
======== Data: 00:05:08.627012 =========            

 00:05:08.627012 ; Bid ; 1.16198 ; 10000000.0
 00:05:08.627012 ; Ask ; 1.16232 ; 10000000.0

========= Data: 00:05:12.721536 =========           

 00:05:08.627012 ; Bid ; 1.16198 ; 10000000.0
 00:05:12.721536 ; Bid ; 1.16209 ; 1000000.0
 00:05:08.627012 ; Ask ; 1.16232 ; 10000000.0
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If `1900-01-01` is always at the beginning and a constant, you could cut off the first 11 chars. To replace the `0` and `1` and use replace (if I undetstood you right), e.g.:

```
row = "1900-01-01 00:05:08.627012 ; 1 ; 1.16232 ; 10000000.0"
row[11:].replace('; 0 ;', '; Bid ;').replace('; 1 ;', '; Ask ;')

>>> '00:05:08.627012 ; Ask ; 1.16232 ; 10000000.0'
```